# excluding particular type of file in ant

Tags: ant

I want to exclude 2 files in every directory, my dir structure is somewhat like this
    /a

```
a.java
asoapbinding.java

/b
b.java
bsoapbinding.java

/c
c.java
csoapbinding.java
.
.
.
```

like this I am having 12 dir, in each I need to exclude 2 files, and keep rest. One file will be having same name as dir is having, and other is having soapbinding in the end. So do I need to use regex, or include/exclude in fileset? Or is there any other better approach to do the same. Kindly let me know, if any more information is required.

Comment: Does <exclude> tag not work?

Comment: It should work, but issue is there are 12 dirs, and I wanna set pattern so that each should exclude those 2 files recursively in all 12 dir

Comment: so not sure about the approach, my main concern is the file need to be excluded which is having the same name which dir has

Answer (score 0):

I would do it manually like this:

```
 <exclude name="**/a/a.java"/>
 <exclude name="**/a/asoapbinding.java"/>
 <exclude name="**/b/b.java"/>
 <exclude name="**/b/bsoapbinding.java"/>
```

etc.

I'm not aware of any more advance regular expression matching in `exclude`

Comment: Thanks, so I need to define all those 24 files in exclude tag :(
ll give a try, and come back if found something new or if it works.
Thanks for help :)